# trouble with drawing graphics file

Tags: android, graphics, drawable

Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);

have saved the ball.png file under res/drawable-hdpi

referenced the R.java file under gen/com/

however the editor shows a problem saying R cannot be resolved to a variable in the R.drawable.ball section of the code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I removed the R label, as the R tag is used for the statistical language (see the tag wiki). And apparently, we're not talking about that one.

Answer (score 0):

See if in your import list (at the top of the file), there is

```
import android.R;
```

and change it to

```
import com.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this helpful tutorial about painting BitMaps:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-2d-canvas-graphics/

You can also try cleaning your project: Menu -> Project -> Clean

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Clean project to solve this problem.